# How to set state using button click in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a boolean isUserLoggedIn = false; in my main.dart file and when  isUserLoggedIn = false i am loading

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: isUserLoggedIn == false ? IntroAuthScreen() : HomePage(),
);
```

This is working fine. IntroAuthScreen is loading. But there is a button in IntroAuthScreen i want the value of isUserLoggedIn to be true when user click the button and he will be redirected to HomePage() as above code show.

IntroAuthCode:-

```
child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.navigate_next,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                username = usernameController.text;
                isUserLoggedIn = true;
              });
              print(username);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            label: Text("Finish"),
          ),
```

but its not working. help me

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code.

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: isUserLoggedIn == false ? IntroAuthScreen() : HomePage(),
        );
    
        IntroAuthScreen() async {
            bool isLoggedIN = await Navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute Bla Bla);
             setState((){
                isUserLoggedIn = isLoggedIN ?? false;
             });
        }
    }
```

In Auth Code

```
child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.navigate_next,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                username = usernameController.text;
                isUserLoggedIn = true;
              });
              print(username);
              Navigator.pop(context, isUserLoggedIn);
            },
            label: Text("Finish"),
          ),
```

Comment: IntroAuthScreen() is a stateful widget

Comment: It's Function where you write how to open Next Screen using Material Page route

Comment: how to add async becuase IntroAuth is a stf widget

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to create a wrapper class rather than switching the content of the scaffold?

Perhaps something like this:

```
class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return (_user == null) ? IntroAuthScreen() : HomeScreen();
  }
}
```

The answer does make use of Provider, but it's definitely a worthwhile package to consider learning.